# Ecommerce Engine for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, e-commerce

I am currently try to develop an web app and its based on RoR. I am planning to add an Ecommerce engine (emarket place) to it as a module. Any recommendation for this? any commercial sources?

I looked at Spreecommerce but not sure if dynamic pricing can be done (like a travel app, where pricing fluctuates or increases)

Basically the price of product increases each time a inventory is sold (think plane tickets increases the more popular a flight is) until a Cap on total price

I am also try to see if i can put "add-ons" to the product being sold.

Any recommendation for this? Or does this engine needs to be done from scratch?

thanks in advance! have a good day

Comment: I know with https://github.com/drhenner/ror_ecommerce you can just turn "variant.price field" into a method.  Note: I created this project

Answer (score 0):

How about Spree? [github](https://github.com/spree/spree), [main site](https://spreecommerce.com/)